# many who had traveled miles for a glimpse of the frozen landscape

Tags: error

Is "many who" used correctly in the following sentence from CNN?

The Saudi photographer, who documented the scenes on January 11, said the site was teeming with visitors, **many who** had traveled miles for a glimpse of the frozen landscape.

https://edition.cnn.com/travel/article/saudi-arabia-snow/index.html

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not correct.

It should be "...visitors, **many of whom** had traveled miles...."

Comment: I agree, Without *of whom*, it seems to say that they were many, and all had traveled miles...